# How to add BIGSERIAL primary key to sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am building an app that has to use few existing databases and one of them (Postgresql) uses BIGSERIAL as its primary key in tables. my question is, how should the column when I add it to sqlalchemy Base, while defining the table?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply create the column with a type of `BigInteger` instead of `Integer`.

If the column is set to autoincrement (`autoincrement=True`, which is the implicit default if you have `primary_key=True` on it), this will result in a `bigserial` column.

---

If you use declarative, it would look like this:

```
id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: And if I do not want to add it as primary key?